# SNR between two images in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab

Below is the algorithm for calculating the SNR of two images in MATLAB:

```
A = imread('Yes_Noise.png');
A = imgaussfilt(A, 2); %Filtered image

ref = imread('Yes_Noise.png'); %Noisy image

test = snr(ref,ref-A)
```

I just want to ask, what does come first and last in the last line? A as the filtered noisy image and REF as the non filtered noisy image (in this particular case I get a positive result)? Or REF as non filtered the noisy image and A as the filtered noisy image (in this particular case I get a negative result)?

Comment: I believe the 2nd argument should be `ref-A` (this is because according to the docs, the 2nd input is the **noise**).

Comment: Please see the edit. Is it what you mean?

Comment: It is indeed what I meant, but I didn't intend that you to edit your question. In any case, `refA-A` or `abs(refA-A)` is _at best_ a rough estimate of the noise magnitude, which is not exactly what the `snr` function needs.

Comment: What would be the most accurate solution?